# SharePoint workflow task with custom content type after properties issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I made a workflow for "Corrective Action". Here the issuer will issue the CA to a user. If he replies to that then the approver should review it. Here for approver i created a content type named "CA Review" for the Task where I added a field "Outcome" which is a drop down.

In the workflow, for the review task, in the method invoking i am attaching the content type to the task. This is working fine and i am able to see the "outcome" in the task edit form.

In the event of task changed, i need the value of "outcome" to set the other filed. Here i am using after properties of the task changed event. But this returns "null". Here is my code for getting the outcome value.

```
private void checkTheRespondeApproval(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
    {
        var props = this.onReviewTaskChanged_AfterProperties1.ExtendedProperties[GetWorkflowFieldId("Outcome")];
        e.Result = (props.ToString() == "Approved");
    }
```

Here "props" is getting "Null". Please help me to get the outcome value. The code for "GetWorkflowFieldID" is as follows;

```
private Guid GetWorkflowFieldId(string pFieldName)
    {
        foreach (SPField item in workflowProperties.Item.Fields)
        {
            if (item.Title == pFieldName)
                return item.Id;
        }

        return Guid.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys,

I found the answer. The problem is for the field ID I am looking into wrong collection. I should get the field id of the content type. The following is the function I wrote to get the ID. It is working now.

```
private Guid GetContentTypeFileID(string pFieldName)
    {
        foreach (SPField item in workflowProperties.Web.ContentTypes["CAReview"].Fields)
        {
            if (item.Title == pFieldName)
                return item.Id;
        }

        return Guid.Empty;
    }
```

I hope this will help you too.